# Baldur's Gate: EE What does this sentence mean?

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs, infinitives

I'm playing a PC game 'Baldur's Gate:EE' and I can't understand this sentence.

It is from a character in the game.

"I bet those rank-ridin' bandits are hired by the Amnian. ***It'd be like those moneygrubbers to pull something so low.*** Got to the point where an honest man can't travel the roads."

In particular, second sentence, I don't get it at all.

It would be like those moneygrubbers to pull something so low.

1. What does **pull something so low** mean?
2. In the sentence, to infinitive(**to pull something so low**) is used as an adjective to describe those moneygrubbers?

Please help me and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please show research. 'Pull something so low' is constructed similarly to 'try/do something so dastardly'. You can look up 'pull' and 'low' for suitable senses. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull) gives a good entry for the (criminal, slang) sense of the verb 'pull' used here.

Comment: It is similar to ["pull a stunt"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-a-stunt) "Low" means underhanded, or unethical.

Comment: All users thank you for your kindness and interest! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

To "pull something so low" is to do something very bad (as bad as what they are talking about, that is). And the rest of the sentence explains that it's expected or normal for moneygrubbers to do such a thing, though normally one would say, "It'd be just like ...".

> **low** [ loh ]
>
> lacking in dignity or elevation, as of thought or expression.
>
> mean, base, or disreputable: low tricks; low companions.
>
> coarse or vulgar: entertainment of a low sort.

---

> **pull**  [ˈpu̇l] [ˈpəl] *transitive verb*
>
> 8a : perform, carry out
>
> pull an all-nighter
>
> pull guard duty

Comment: Just to add a bit of clarification, "pull something so low" isn't a single well-known idiom, it's a combination of two-- "pull" (i.e. 'do') and "low" (i.e. 'disreputable' or 'dirty')

Comment: Yes, however I think it's fairly common to say "pull something so ....." with the last word being negative (e.g. stupid, rash, etc.).